# Flatsome theme don't show cart span title for Tablets edit:Solved_after_staring_at_screen_for_1_day

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Flatsome theme don't show cart span title for Tablets
This is a screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNZjf.png)
I want it to look like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGY7e.png)
For phones it's perfect
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJCmT.png)
This is the @media code:

```
@media (max-width: 549px) {
  .hide-for-small,
  [data-show="hide-for-small"] {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .small-text-center {
    float: none !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  .show-for-small,
  [data-show="show-for-small"] {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 850px) {
  .show-for-medium,
  [data-show="show-for-medium"] {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 849px) {
  .hide-for-medium,
  [data-show="hide-for-medium"] {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .medium-text-center .pull-left,
  .medium-text-center .pull-right {
    float: none;
  }
  .medium-text-center .ml {
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  .medium-text-center .mr {
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  .medium-text-center {
    float: none !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 850px) {
  .hide-for-large,
  [data-show="hide-for-large"] {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

This is the code source

```
`<li class="header-divider"></li>
                  <li class="cart-item has-icon">
                    <div class="header-button">
                      <a
                        href="https://localhost/artima"
                        class="header-cart-link off-canvas-toggle nav-top-link icon primary button circle is-small"
                        data-open="#cart-popup"
                        data-class="off-canvas-cart"
                        title="Cart"
                        data-pos="right"
                      >
                        <span class="header-cart-title"> Cart </span>

                        <i class="icon-shopping-basket" data-icon-label="0">
                        </i>
                      </a>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Cart Sidebar Popup -->
                    <div id="cart-popup" class="mfp-hide widget_shopping_cart">
                      <div class="cart-popup-inner inner-padding">
                        <div class="cart-popup-title text-center">
                          <h4 class="uppercase">Cart</h4>
                          <div class="is-divider"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="widget_shopping_cart_content">
                          <p class="woocommerce-mini-cart__empty-message">
                            No products in the cart.
                          </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cart-sidebar-content relative"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>

              <!-- Mobile Right Elements -->
              <div class="flex-col show-for-medium flex-right">
                <ul class="mobile-nav nav nav-right">
                  <li class="cart-item has-icon">
                    <div class="header-button">
                      <a
                        href="https://localhost/artima"
                        class="header-cart-link off-canvas-toggle nav-top-link icon primary button circle is-small"
                        data-open="#cart-popup"
                        data-class="off-canvas-cart"
                        title="Cart"
                        data-pos="right"
                      >
                        <i class="icon-shopping-basket" data-icon-label="0">
                        </i>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="container">
              <div class="top-divider full-width"></div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="header-bg-container fill">
            <div class="header-bg-image fill"></div>
            <div class="header-bg-color fill"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>

      <main id="main" class="">
        <div id="content" role="main" class="content-area"></div>
      </main>`
```

Thanks for everyone who is trying to help !

I Tried modifying the @media code but no luck
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGLE1.png)
For this image i just injected the span title "copied it from the code for desktop ctrl+c and ctrl+v"

Actually i managed to solve it just add this code to header-main.php

```
<!-- Right Elements -->
          <div class="flex-col hide-for-medium hide-for-small flex-right">
            <ul class="header-nav header-nav-main nav nav-right <?php flatsome_nav_classes('main'); ?>">
              <?php flatsome_header_elements('header_elements_right'); ?>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <!-- Tablet Right Elements -->
          <div class="flex-col hide-for-small hide-for-large flex-right">
            <ul class="header-nav nav nav-right <?php flatsome_nav_classes('main'); ?>">
              <?php flatsome_header_elements('header_mobile_elements_right'); ?>
                
              </ul>
          </div>
          
          <!-- Mobile Right Elements -->
          <div class="flex-col show-for-small flex-right">
            <ul class="mobile-nav nav nav-right <?php flatsome_nav_classes('main-mobile'); ?>">
              <?php flatsome_header_elements('header_mobile_elements_right','mobile'); ?>
                
              </ul>
          </div>
```

I have added Tablet Right Elements the devs just ignored that little mistake
actually it took for me 1 day to figure it out
Thanx again to @Chris Haas who tried to help me !

Comment: "Flatsome theme don't show..." when something isn't showing, inspect it and its parents to see why. Also, just a warning that once you start using `!important` you are often forced to keep using it over and over and it sometimes/often bites you.

Comment: @Chris Haas How can i view the actual source file in my hard disk because i can't find it to edit it

Comment: You want to inspect most likely, not view source. Just right-click the thing you are interested in and select _Inspect_.

Comment: i know how to fix it but i can't

Comment: <div class="header-button">      <a href="https://localhost/artima?customize_changeset_uuid=f743eed8-f28e-442c-8022-a5874db91535&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0" class="header-cart-link off-canvas-toggle nav-top-link icon primary button circle is-small" data-open="#cart-popup" data-class="off-canvas-cart" title="Cart" data-pos="right">
  
      <i class="icon-shopping-basket" data-icon-label="0">
  </i>
// I need to add this span to the source file php html or whatever   <span class="menu-title uppercase hide-for-small">Cart</span>//
</a></div>

Comment: @Chris Haas read the comment after the <i> element

Comment: "I need to add this span to the source file php html or whatever" - You need to add the span, or make it visible? I'm not really clear. Do whatever you are doing in the media query that works is about all I can tell you.